# React set state with variable that is nested

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate

I have an input that looks like

```
<input name="data.company.name" value="Bob's Burgers" />
```

and on it's onChange I'd like to update the state with it's name.

```
<input name="data.company.name" value="Bob's Burgers" onChange={(e) => this.setState({ [e.name]: e.target.value}) />
```

But when I do this the state looks like

```
this.state = {
   data: { company: { name: '' } },
   data.company.name: "Bob's Burgers"
}
```

How can I achieve passing the name to the state so I end up with

```
this.state = {
   data: { company: { name: "Bob's Burgers" } }
}
```

I cannot alter the name of the input as it's set via a Field Component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind adding lodash to your project you could do [this](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1696#issuecomment-328335502):

```
<input
  name="data.company.name"
  value="Bob's Burgers"
  onChange={e =>
    e.persist();
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return _.setWith(_.clone(prevState), e.name, e.target.value, _.clone);
    });
  }
/>;
```

Comment: e is coming back undefined in setState ?

Comment: @Ryan I think `persist()` is needed, I updated the answer

Comment: Yep, it was.  I had just added it as you submitted your answer.  thank you!

Comment: Also, good call with lodash. I always forget I can do so much with it